# MongoDB get remaining seats of restaurant

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've problem to find remaining seats of particular restaurant in a particular `Date range`

Let me define my problem. Suppose I've a collection it called `booking`

In this have a following fields:

- Booking ID
- User ID
- Restaurant ID
- Booking Start Date (date saved in Timestamp)
- Booking End Date (date saved in Timestamp)
- Booked Seat

[image]

If there are ***50*** seats in restaurant. And I want to check available seats of a particular date range for example the date range is ***`6-12`***(This range in timestamp)"(Start Date) - (End Date)"

How to calculate the total remaining seats of restaurant.

If anyone have any idea please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Code is here

```
const where = {};
where.restaurant_id = 126;
where.user_id = 1;
where.start_date = { $gte: 6 };
where.end_date = { $gte: 12 };
const remainingSeats = getSeatsAvailability(where);

function getSeatsAvailability(where) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bookingModel.find(where, (err, details) => {
      if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(details); }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Add your code first

Comment: Please post what you have already tried. check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask.

Comment: source code added @Priyank

Comment: code added @AritraChakraborty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, What I have Visualized is the below diagram, so there are basically four cases to be covered:

```
            x            y
a-----------|---------b  |
          a-|------------|---b
            |  a-------b |
            |      a-----|--------b
```

So the formulae are:

```
1. a<x, a<y | b>x, b<y
2. a<x, a<y | b>x, b>y
3. a>x, a<y | b>x, b>y
4. a>x, a<y | b<y, b>x
```

I am pasting an *ROUGH* example, take it as a hint to solve the problem at hand:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          a: {
            $lte: 3,
            $lte: 9
          },
          $or: [
            {
              b: {
                $gte: 3,
                $lte: 9
              }
            },
            {
              b: {
                $gte: 3,
                $gte: 9
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          a: {
            $gte: 3,
            $lte: 9
          },
          $or: [
            {
              b: {
                $gte: 3,
                $gte: 9
              }
            },
            {
              b: {
                $gte: 3,
                $lte: 9
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      r: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      sum_booked: {
        $sum: "$c"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      seats_left: {
        $subtract: [
          50,
          "$sum_booked"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The example dataset that I have tested on:

```
[
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 10,
    c: 10,
    r: 1,

  },
  {
    a: 2,
    b: 5,
    c: 15,
    r: 1
  },
  {
    a: 5,
    b: 10,
    c: 10,
    r: 1
  },
  {
    a: 7,
    b: 15,
    c: 15,
    r: 12 <<<<========/////DIFF REST ID
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "seats_left": 15
  }
]
```

Comment: You checked with date range ```6-12``` . If you can see in your example dataset that you've tested on check the second element of object ```{
    a: 2,
    b: 5,
    c: 15,
    r: 1
  },``` in this the range is ```2-5``` . so this slot also available after ```5``` then answer should be ```30 seat left``` not a ```15```

Comment: Yes you are right! Silly mistake, edited the answer.

Comment: Aritra ,for this ```6-12``` time slot your's answer is right. But user can give any time slot suppose I gave a slot for example ```3-9``` according to your code it return ```[ { _id: null, seats_left: 25 } ]``` but actually in that time slot there will be ```15``` seat. Thanks

Comment: Changed the code entirely, added a diagram, if any of the cases are missed then feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.booking.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            BookingStartDate: { $lte: date_range_end },
            BookingEndDate: { $gte: date_range_start },
            RestaurantID: restaurant_id
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$RestaurantID',
            TotalBookedSeat: { $sum: '$BookedSeat' }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            LeftSeat: { $subtract: [50, '$TotalBookedSeat'] },
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d8479f6902a52448029a6d0"), "bid" : 1, "uid" : 1, "rid" : 126, "bsd" : 1, "bed" : 10, "bs" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d847a11902a52448029a6d1"), "bid" : 2, "uid" : 1, "rid" : 126, "bsd" : 2, "bed" : 5, "bs" : 15 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d847a24902a52448029a6d2"), "bid" : 3, "uid" : 1, "rid" : 126, "bsd" : 5, "bed" : 10, "bs" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d847a34902a52448029a6d3"), "bid" : 4, "uid" : 1, "rid" : 126, "bsd" : 7, "bed" : 15, "bs" : 15 }

db.booking.aggregate([{ $match: { bsd: { $lte: 12 }, bed: { $gte: 6 }, rid: 126 } }, { $group: { _id: '$rid', total_seat_sold: { $sum: '$bs' } } }])

The result of the above is 35, then 15 seats left.
```

This time it will works I think.

Comment: you matched only single condition  ```BookingStartDate: { $lte: timestamp },
            BookingEndDate: { $gte: timestamp }, ``` not working